# jpql IN query with enum value

Tags: java, enums, jpql

I am using JPQL query to check whether the list contains the specified enum values. If the enum value is a single element to check then it is pretty simple.

In query expression,

```
query = "... where s.status = :status";
```

and then set parameter like

```
query.setParameter("status", statusValue);
```

**But I want to check something like below**

```
query = "... where s.status IN (:statusList)";
```

where `statusList` is a string of numbers (e.g. "0,1,2" which means the list of the values of status)

But I can't find a solution. I have also checked with `s.status.ordinal() IN (statusList)` in query but no luck.

I'm using JPA Implementation: EclipseLink (JPA 2.0)

My Entity's actual name is `SType`

```
public enum SType
{
    REQUISITION,
    PURCHASE,   
    FINISHED,   
    // others
    RETURN;
}
```

**QUERY:**

```
String querySt = "select s.slipType.slipNameSt,s.slipNumberSt, s.idNr from Slip s 
where s.slipType.sType IN (:enumTypeListt)";

em.createQuery(querySt).setParameter("enumTypeList", EnumSet.of(SType.REQUISITION, 
                                                                SType.PURCHASE));
```

Comment: Your persisting the ordinal value as opposed to the String?

Comment: @KevinBowersox: Yes, in database, I stored the ordinal values and in front-end, Enum represents that value.

Comment: I would advise storing the actual String of the enum in the database.  If your enum ever changes you may need to perform some data adjustment in your database.

Comment: @KevinBowersox: I am really sorry that I can't change the db at this point. the system has lots of data and live. So, I need some other solution. Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't compare enums with strings or integers. The persistent field is of type Status, which is an enum (or at least, let's suppose the type is Status, since you didn't specify the name of the enum class).

So, what you must pass as argument for the collection in the `IN` clause is a collection of Status. For example:

```
query = "... where s.status IN :statusList";
...
q.setParameter("statusList", EnumSet.of(Status.APPROVED, Status.CLOSED));
```

Comment: I got the following error: "You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.RegularEnumSet for parameter statusList with expected type of class SType from query ...". what can I do now?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't replace `IN` by `=`? If not, please edit the question and tell us which JPA implementation you're using, show us the code of the entity and the code you're using to execute the query, as well as the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Sorry, I had a bug in my query. I fixed it now: no need for parentheses arount the statusList parameter.